Get list of all Oracle JDK releases for a specific version using curl or rest api call
I would like to programmatically get a listing of all Oracle JDK releases so that upon detecting a new release trigger a pipeline to upgrade JDK (in effect programmatically getting and listing Oracle Jdk download links listing)
I have searched for an oracle download url/page containing release folders per Jdk versions but have not been able to find any.
Is there a way to accomplish this using a curl call on an oracle download page or using a rest api call (similar to what can be done for listing azul Zulu Jdk releases simply by getting a listing of the azul bin folder (https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin)
Thanks.
Tried searching for oracle Jdk download links that could be listed programmatically. Could not find any.

The Java Version Almanac
The Java Version Almanac is a resource rich with data about versions of Java, and versions of JDK products from most every vendor. The vendors include:
[
  "adoptium",
  "adoptopenjdk",
  "alibaba",
  "amazon",
  "azul",
  "bellsoft",
  "ibm",
  "microsoft",
  "oracle",
  "redhat",
  "sap"
]

The software and the data is open-source.
You can call a Web API to get JSON data. See this Swagger editor. You can try the calls live on that editor site.
You likely want the /jdk/vendors/{vendor} call. For example, get a list of JDK products offered by SAP.
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://data.javaalmanac.io/v1/jdk/vendors/sap' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'

Result:
{
  "name": "SAP",
  "url": "https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/",
  "products": [
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 10",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-10%22",
      "platforms": [
        "alpine-x64",
        "linux-ppc64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "10"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 11",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/latest/11",
      "platforms": [
        "linux-arm64",
        "linux-ppc64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-arm64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "11"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 12",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-12%22",
      "platforms": [
        "linux-ppc64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "12"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 13",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-13%22",
      "platforms": [
        "linux-ppc64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "13"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 14",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-14%22",
      "platforms": [
        "linux-ppc64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "14"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 15",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-15%22",
      "platforms": [
        "linux-ppc64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "15"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 16",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-16%22",
      "platforms": [
        "linux-ppc64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "16"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 17",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/latest/17",
      "platforms": [
        "alpine-x64",
        "linux-arm64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-arm64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "17"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 18",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-18%22",
      "platforms": [
        "linux-arm64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-arm64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "18"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 19",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-19%22",
      "platforms": [
        "linux-arm64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-arm64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "19"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 20",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-20%22",
      "platforms": [
        "alpine-x64",
        "linux-arm64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-arm64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "20"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 21",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/latest/21",
      "platforms": [
        "aix-ppc64",
        "alpine-x64",
        "linux-arm64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-arm64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "21"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 22",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/latest/22",
      "platforms": [
        "aix-ppc64",
        "alpine-x64",
        "linux-arm64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-arm64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "22"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    },
    {
      "id": "sap_machine",
      "name": "SapMachine 23",
      "license": "GPLv2+CE",
      "url": "https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases?q=%22sapmachine-23%22",
      "platforms": [
        "aix-ppc64",
        "alpine-x64",
        "linux-arm64",
        "linux-ppc64le",
        "linux-x64",
        "macos-arm64",
        "macos-x64",
        "windows-x64"
      ],
      "versions": [
        "23"
      ],
      "foojaydownload": true
    }
  ]
}

SDKMAN!
SDKMAN! is a command-line tool for listing, downloading, and installing Java JDKs (and other software kits).
The list of JDK products known to SDKMAN! come from voluntary submissions by the JDK vendors. Not all vendors choose to submit their product info.
sdk list java 

